# Aggregate elements based on position vector

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I'm trying to vectorize a very simple operation but can't seem to figure out how.

Given a very large numerical vector (over 1M positions) and another array of size n with a given set of positions, I would like to get back a vector of size n with elements being the average of the values of the first vector as specified by the second

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
b = np.array([[0,1],[2],[3,5],[4,6]])

c = [1.5,3,5,6]
```

I need to repeat this operation many times so performance is an issue.

Vanilla python solution:

```
import numpy as np
import time

a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
b = np.array([[0,1],[2],[3,5],[4,6]])

begin = time.time()

for i in range(100000):

    c = []

    for d in b:
        c.append(np.mean(a[d]))

print(time.time() - begin, c)
# 3.7529971599578857 [1.5, 3.0, 5.0, 6.0]
```

Comment: `np.fromiter(map(lambda i: a[i].mean(), b), np.float)` is a simple way. Maybe there is some more efficient `numpy` method I'm missing

Comment: thanks! looks like a handy function, however it doesn't seem to execute faster than a vanilla python implementation

Comment: So, `a` is large but is `b` also large? One solution would be to iterate over `b`, use fancy indexing on `a` and then call mean on the indexed result. Is this your "vanilla python" solution? E.g `[a[inds].mean() for inds in b]`

Comment: Are the positions in `b` always sequential? That is, are you always computing the mean of contiguous slices of `a`, or can the indices in `b` be in any order, or even repeated?

Comment: About `fromiter`, it is okay to use, but consider passing `count=len(b)` for efficiency.

Comment: How are your indices structured? Do they follow and order and make up all of the array as in your example? Or are they completely random? In the first case, maybe you can compute `a.cumsum()`, select the first element of `b` and compute the difference

Comment: is pandas an option for you? inside a pandas DataFrame you could do a .groupby() and mean()

Comment: sorry, the indices are unique, but not in order/sequential, I fixed the example to clarify (cumsum is not an option). pandas is an option, but I still can't figure out how to do this without creating a huge table or loops. the problem is that I need to repeat this operation 1M times also, so I'd rather go for memory costs rather than cpu times (ie. creating a huge table rather than doing a million iterations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is necessarily faster but you may as well try:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
b = np.array([[0, 1], [2], [3, 5], [4, 6]])

# Get the length of each subset of indices
lens = np.fromiter((len(bi) for bi in b), count=len(b), dtype=np.int32)
# Compute reduction indices
reduce_idx = np.roll(np.cumsum(lens), 1)
reduce_idx[0] = 0
# Make flattened array of index lists
idx = np.fromiter((i for bi in b for i in bi), count=lens.sum(), dtype=np.int32)
# Reorder according to indices
a2 = a[idx]
# Sum reordered array at reduction indices and divide by number of indices
c = np.add.reduceat(a2, reduce_idx) / lens
print(c)
# [1.5 3.  5.  6. ]
```

Comment: it is 25% faster than doing `for i in range(len(b)): c.append(np.mean(a[b[i]]))`, which is not bad, but I was hoping for a significantly larger improvement (by that I mean something that could run at least 10 times faster than the simple python loop)

Comment: @Sovos You can get that kind of speedup if you replace your array of lists with a flat array of index integers and another array with the size of each sublist (that is, if you give `idx` and `lens` as input in the above code, correspondingly). I don't know where you get your data from, but if you can change the encoding of the array segments with that, then skipping those two steps in my solution makes it over 10x faster.

Comment: sorry, you are perfectly right. that helped alot, thanks!